# Intersection between Parabola and Sine

Tags: calculus

Is it true that a parabola and some sine function can only intersect at most twice?

How to prove / disprove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can find a counter-example like $x^2$ and $sin(9x)$:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2+and+sin(9x)

Since they intersect more than twice, this proves that the claim is not true.